# Iterating through a column and mapping values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

Here is what I am trying to do.
I want to substitute the values of this data frame.
[image]

For example. Bernard to be substituted as 1, and then Drake as 2 and so on and so forth.
How to iterate through the column to write a function that can do the following.

Comment: provide minimal reproducible code/data and include your expected output and avoid screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function already exists - [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).

It returns a tuple - first a new column with the values each item has been mapped to. Then second an index of the unique values.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bernard', 'Bernard', 'Drake', 'Drake', 'Lance']})
pd.factorize(df.name)
```

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), Index(['Bernard', 'Drake', 'Lance'], dtype='object'))
```

Using that, we'd just assign a new column:

```py
df = df.assign(codes=pd.factorize(df.name)[0] + 1)
df
```

```
      name  codes
0  Bernard      1
1  Bernard      1
2    Drake      2
3    Drake      2
4    Lance      3
```

Comment: Good answer, thank you for contributing.  However you shouldn't post images of code or data.  Please edit your answer and paste the code and output and format accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
data = {
    'Name' : ['My Name', 'My Name', 'Your Name', 'Your Name'],
    'Date' : ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount() + 1
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in category codes to achieve this:

```
df.Name.astype('category').cat.codes+1
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary and the map

```
dict = {'bernard':1, 'drake':2, 'sansa':3}
df['code'] = df['name'].map(dict)
```

```
    name    date    code
0   bernard 01/11/2020  1
1   drake   01/11/2020  2
2   sansa   01/11/2020  3
```

is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I wanted to use it for a more generalized data frame, where the number of rows is higher. For the above data frame, this would work but for a larger data set, it would be too cumbersome

Comment: this solution work when you have predetermined values to map back to the names instead of auto generated values